# ¿Existe alguna traducción o equivalente para "Sugar daddy/mummy" y "sugar baby" en español?

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término

He escuchado varias veces los términos *sugar daddy/mummy* y *sugar baby* para referirse a una relación generalmente basada en el interés, donde la persona mayor (daddy/mummy) le proporciona beneficios econónimos al sugar baby a cambio de compañía y demás.

¿Se puede expresar ese tipo de relación en español sin perder los matices del significado? Con esto me refiero a que:

- No solamente es la diferencia de edad, es también un intercambio de favores.
- Es algo consensuado.
- Por ser de mutuo acuerdo (implícito o explícito) nadie se está "aprovechando" del otro.

Comment: Define compañía: es sexual o meramente de compartir espcios?

Comment: @fedorqui supongo que dependerá del tipo de favores intercambiados...

Comment: @fedorqui yo supongo que puede variar. Por ejemplo, en una página dice: _Our specialty is connecting people to sugar mummies/daddies for sexual and financial gains. Meeting could involve escort, sex and just hanging out to make the sugar client happy_

Comment: Lo único que se me ocurre es el peyorativo _asaltacunas_, que se emplea para las personas que gustan de ligar con gente de mucha menos edad.

Comment: @Charlie I think we call them cradle snatcher too which is not the same as a sugar daddy which could be a neutral term.

Comment: Tras activar el modo de navegación privada, he visto que algunos sitios mencionan el término "bebé azucarero". No sé en qué países se usa, ni si es común, ni si se puede decir también "papá azucarero" o "mami azucarera".

Comment: No existe una expresión o palabra del español común que sirva como sinónimo a sugar daddy, y si la hay, sólo serán expresiones locales de cada país/región.

Comment: padrote, matrona  ?

Answer (score 4):

No creo que haya un análogo exacto, pero existe la palabra [**"mantenido"**](https://dle.rae.es/srv/search?m=30&w=mantenido), que exprese un concepto similar que "sugar baby".

Comment: mantenido no es lo mismo. Sugar daddy refleja también una diferencia de edad, mientras que una 'mantenida' es una mujer que vive a costa de un hombre, generalmente su pareja formal, no tiene por qué haber diferencia de edad

Answer (score 2):

He buscado un término que implique la idea de prostitución inexplícita o de baja intensidad. Lo único que satisface esos términos es la palabra cubana "jinetera" (o "jinetero"), donde hay cierta "amistad" de conveniencia, normalmente con sexo y la retribución mediante, regalos, aportaciones a la familia, etc. No es netamente prostitución, pues no se cobra por servicio realizado. Es lo que más cerca está de "sugar baby" sin salirnos del español y sin entrar en neologismos.

Answer (score 1):

En ['Zola', la historia en 148 tuits de una 'stripper' que se ha convertido en una película](https://verne.elpais.com/verne/2020/01/26/articulo/1580051714_408122.html) reproducen una serie de tuits de una aventura rocambolesca. Escrita originalmente en inglés, el periódico lo traduce al castellano y en ella aparece el concepto *sugar baby*.

En concreto, traduce el concepto como *novio viejo y rico*:

> ¡Sí, tía, yo también! Entonces me dice que el tipo negro enorme es su sugar daddy (**su novio viejo y rico**) y yo le digo sí tía, mi sugar daddy está en casa, te entiendo, te entiendo.

Answer (score 1):

Hay una buena variedad de opciones en [linguee](https://www.linguee.com/english-spanish/translation/sugar+daddy.html):

- hombre mayor
- tío rico
- un proxeneta
- hombre maduro
- gavilán
- viejo adinerado
- relación trans-generacional
- papito
- protector
- amante mayor
- padrino
- viejo verde

Si es explotación o simbiosis varia de una situación a otra.  Por lo tanto, creo que no hay una sola traducción *one size fits all* para todo caso.